# In the settings.gradle file how can i dynamically include all the subprojects?

Tags: gradle, groovy

As **settings.gradle** file runs on groovy is it possible to write a script which will include all the subprojects which contains for example **build.gradle** files inside it.

I tried using this

```
new File('.').eachFileRecurse {
    if (it.name.endsWith("build.gradle")) {
        //include it
        println "Processing file ${it}"
    }
}
```

but can't figure out how it will work. I mean how will i include all my subprojects

I don't want to hardcode include 'x', include 'y' in the settings.gradle file

Comment: Have you tried `include(it.parent)`?

Comment: It throws an error " Multiple projects in this build have project directory ".

Comment: Ignore `.` then?

Comment: Yes it does the job. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can call `include` with the parent of the locations where the
`build.gradle` files are found.  Be careful to not include things
multiple times or the root itself by the net you are casting.

E.g.

```
new File('.').eachFileRecurse {
    if (it.name == "build.gradle" /* && ... more checks */)) {
        println "Included directory ${it.name} due to ${it}"
        include it.parent
    }
}
```